# To show $\lim_{\xi \to 1} (\xi -1) L(\xi,\chi_{0}) = \frac{\Phi(N)}{N}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

How to show if $\chi_{0}$ is the trivial $\text{Dirichlet Character}$ then $$\lim_{\xi \to 1} (\xi -1) L(\xi,\chi_{0}) = \frac{\Phi(N)}{N}$$

where $\Phi$ is the $\text{Euler's Totient}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some hints:

- Use the product formula for $L(s, \chi) = \displaystyle\prod_{p} \biggl(1- \frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}\biggr)^{-1}$. Note $\chi_{0}(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & p \nmid n \\\ 0 & p \mid n\end{array}\right.$
- Use the formula $\Phi(n) = \displaystyle n \cdot \prod_{p} \biggl(1-\frac{1}{p}\biggr)$
- Use the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{z \to 1}\: (z-1)\:\zeta(z) =1$.

Complete solution:

> See page 10 of the following  [link](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/dirichlet.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.